# Qual è il significato di "baffi melensi"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal* di Luigi Pirandello ho letto:

> Scivolava tutto: gli scivolavano nel lungo faccione di qua e di là, le sopracciglia e gli occhi; gli scivolava il naso su i **baffi melensi** e sul pizzo; gli scivolavano dall'attaccatura del collo le spalle; gli scivolava il pancione languido, enorme, quasi fino a terra, perché, data l'imminenza di esso su le gambette tozze, il sarto, per vestirgli quelle gambette, era costretto a tagliargli quanto mai agiati i calzoni; cosicché, da lontano, pareva che indossasse invece, bassa bassa, una veste, e che la pancia gli arrivasse fino a terra.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "melenso" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che sembri poter usarsi per qualificare i baffi. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "baffi melensi"?

Comment: I baffi vengono menzionati altrove, anche senza quest'aggettivo? C'è qualcosa che faccia pensare che i baffi conferiscano a questo personaggio un aspetto sciocco?

Comment: @DaG: Penso che non se ne parli più.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'autore sta fornendo una descrizione di un personaggio accentuandone tutti gli aspetti poco gradevoli.

In questo contesto la parola melensi, riferita ai baffi, credo possa essere interpretata come "insignificanti" nel senso di "poco originali" o "tutt'altro che gradevoli".

Bisogna tenere presente che i baffi, se ben tenuti, erano un motivo di orgoglio e manifestavano la "forte personalità" di chi li portava.

Credo che l'autore abbia voluto togliere ogni connotazione positiva ai baffi della persona descritta.

Answer (score 1):

Nel caso da te citato penso che il [significato di melenso riportato da Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/melenso/) che meglio si adatta è ***goffaggine di aspetto***.

Infatti, come riportato nel libro [Le strategie del testo: introduzione all'analisi retorica della letteratura](https://books.google.it/books?id=T73lz4Y15iUC&pg=PT23&lpg=PT23&dq=baffi%20melensi&source=bl&ots=t1OMBulF6V&sig=6yHUb0SYUY1bw3l6sTyd9KHBAWk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikxfLr8a_SAhXKuxQKHVGVAEsQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=baffi%20melensi&f=false)

> La caricatura del Malagna, in *Il fu Mattia Pascal (1904)* è
>   determinata dall'impiego metaforico del verbo *"scivolare"*

quindi essendo una [caricatura (Treccani)](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caricatura/) ha lo scopo di fornire un

> ritratto che, senza abolire la rassomiglianza con la persona, ne
>   accentua in modo ridicolo o satirico i tratti caratteristici

Comment: E quindi “baffi goffi”? Cioè?

Comment: Come se i baffi stessi, quasi dotati di "poca intelligenza propria e inoltre svogliati", contribuissero a loro volta ad accentuare l'aspetto goffo del personaggio